# What means CS and CSMap?

Tags: ada

I'm very new to Ada, I saw below code for Ada example could any one explain what it does,

```
--
-- An array of array (which is different from a 2-d array).
--
with Gnat.Io; use Gnat.Io;
procedure Arr4 is
    type CS is (G_Wiggins, M_Wiggins, Bennet, Woodall);
    type CSMap is array (CS) of Integer;
    A: array (1..3) of CSMap :=((4, 8, 17, 34),(9, 11, 3, -2),(6, 21, 2, 18));
    I: Integer;
    P: CS;
    Row: CSMap;
begin
    -- Print it the usual way.
    for I in 1..3 loop
        for P in CS loop
            Put(A(I)(P));
            Put(" ");
        end loop;
        New_Line;
     end loop;
     New_Line;
end Arr4;
```

here what exactly CS and CSMap meant ?

Comment: The name of programming language is Ada, which is ladies name, not acronym; ADA is Americans with Disabilities Act (or whatever else it may stand for) so I recommend you to fix your spelling. That way your post may show in case-sensitive google search.

Answer (score 5):

CS is an enumeration, CSMap is an array indexed by that enumeration. A is an array of CSMaps.

What they mean is unclear because `CS` is a *terrible* choice for a variable name (outside of some context which we don't have) : `Computing_Student` would be a much better example and prepare you for, say, final exam scores. Even if you're compiling Ada for a target with 1K memory, longer names won't affect the object size.

But `CSMap` or `Computing_Student_Map` could represent the scores in one test, and `A` could represent the exam scores for each term. Quite how a student can score -2 is not my concern!

The program is simply a pair of nested loops printing all the values : A(I) selects a CSMap, and (P) accesses the P'th member of it.

Does that clear things up?

EDIT : also note poor practice leading to potential bugs:

```
for I in 1..3 loop
```

The intent is *probably* to index over all the values in array A. If that is so, it would be better to guarantee that by writing

```
for I in A'range loop
```

then when someone changes the size of array A, the loop still works as intended...